# Dynamically added attr in ui.item of nestedSortable do not show

Tags: jquery, attributes, jquery-ui-sortable

I have this kind of code:

```
<ol class="champs_form ui-sortable">
    <li class="groupe ui-sortable-handle" g_id="88"><ol></ol></li>
</ol>
```

I tryed:

```
$("ol.champs_form, .champs_form ol").nestedSortable({
    revert: true,
    placeholder: 'placeholder',
    update: function(event, ui) {
        alert(ui.item.closest("li.groupe").attr("g_id") + " -- "+  $(this).closest("li").attr("g_id"));
        theID = 3;
        ui.item.attr("g_id",theID);    
     }
})
```

When I drag a new item

```
<li class="groupe"><ol></ol><li>
```

into my

```
ol.champs_form
```

The results is as follow in FireBug:

```
<ol class="champs_form ui-sortable">
    <li class="groupe ui-sortable-handle" g_id="88">
        <ol>
            <li class="groupe" g_id="3"><ol></ol></li>
        </ol>
    <li>
</ol>
```

Then I drag another

```
<li class="groupe"><ol></ol><li>
```

My alert always return **Undefined -- 88**, when I insert from the second level of **li** when it is suppose to return 3!

and

```
ui.item.closest("li.groupe").parent().html()
```

In contrast to Firebug, always show me the initial **li** without the **g_id="3"**

Thank you,
Vincent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution, it's not elegant, but its working.

```
lastIndex = $('ol.champs_form li').index(ui.item);
closestParent = $("ol.champs_form li:eq("+lastIndex+")").closest("ol").closest("li").attr("g_id");
```